How can CKEditor 5 apply a class on link even when its content is an image
The problem: how to add an option to the CKEditor 5 which can add a custom css style class to a link, even if the content of the link is an image with any alignment? And, of course, preserve the ability to select any alignment.
What I Tried
Style Plugin - Link
Enabled and configured CKEditor 5 Style plugin in Drupal text format settings; added following configuration:
a.my-style|My style

Result:

Can select the class and apply in the editor when the content of the link is text or inline aligned image.
Cannot select the class (the style widget is disabled) when the content of the link is image aligned left, center, right, or block.

Style Plugin - Image
Enabled and configured CKEditor 5 Style plugin; added following configuration:
img.my-style|My style #2

(Had to add the "#2", because Drupal refuses to define multiple styles with the same label even if it's for completely different elements.)
The idea is that I add the class to the image itself and then implement custom text filter which finds all such images and adds the class to the parent link or create it if it doesn't exist.
Result:

The text format configuration form refuses to save this class with error "The <img> tag is not yet supported by the Style plugin."

When looking around the code (Drupal), I found a comment linking this CKEditor 5 issue - it's not currently supported and doesn't seem to be in progress. Maybe in some undetermined future.
Custom Link Toggle
I tried to find out how to add a custom button or toggle to the CKEditor 5 link dialog which would add the style regardless of the Style Plugin.
Couldn't find anything.
Custom Image Toggle
The idea is same as in the Style Plugin - Image section above, but add a button for the custom class to the CKEditor 5 image dialog.
Created a custom Drupal module with file custom_module.ckeditor5.yml:
custom_module_custom_image_style:
  ckeditor5:
    plugins: []
    config:
      image:
        toolbar:
          - '|'
          - 'imageStyle:custom-style'
          - '|'
        styles:
          options:
            - name: 'custom-style'
              icon: 'left'
              title: 'Test #1'
              className: 'custom-style'
              modelElements: [ 'imageBlock', 'imageInline' ]
  drupal:
    label: 'Test #2'
    elements:
      - <img class>

Result:

The button appears, it adds the class when clicked, but it resets alignment. That's a problem, the custom class should be additive, not replacement for alignment.

Also tried to update the configuration to use a dropdown, but the effect is the same.
Sources:

ckeditor5.ckeditor5.yml file in the Drupal source code.
CKEditor 5 architecture Drupal documentation.
CKEditor 5 API overview Drupal documentation.
image/imageconfig CKEditor 5 documentation.

Editor Advanced link module
The Editor Advanced link module allows to set class to a link (class field instead of style dropdown.) That's not exactly user-friendly, but it could be a way.
However, it's known bug that the widget won't save attributes like that if image alignment is set to certain values. The bug was reported at March 2023, so it doesn't seem to be fixed anytime soon.
Similar bug was reported to CKEditor 5 project, but they throw the ball back to the Drupal as it's Drupal module, not supported by CKEditor 5.

You’ll need to write (or find) a custom JS CKEditor plugin, there’s no other way to accomplish this. The closest you could get with just config would be to use link decorators, but sadly CKEditor’s LinkImage plugin is buggy as hell and doesn’t support them properly, even though it’s supposedly “core” functionality. Your current 3rd attempt fails because the imageStyle plugin only supports one value at a time. Your custom plugin would need to subscribe to upcast/downcast events, alter the schema of the image block, image inline, and link plugins. Lots of work unfortunately

@Clive I see, thank you for your answer. For me, it would be even more work (learning) as my knowledge and experience don't include JS/TS and writing plugins for CKE5, my focus with this project is primarily Drupal, so I'll look at some workaround (probably via custom filter.)
Btw. didn't you post another comment? I think I saw it before, but wanted to wait with reply until my frustration from CKE5 calms down in order to write civil answer...

I did, but I deleted it as it wasn’t very useful (it was more about the frustrations you’re talking about with CKEditor). For the record, this piqued my interest and I spent a while writing a few different plugins to try to solve this. I gave it up as a bad job, I’m now convinced there’s no reasonable way to do it without rewriting the entire image/link integration in CKEditor itself, and the original implementation is buggy, so there’s nothing reliable to copy from. If you can solve this with a filter, I highly recommend going down that route :)

Also for the record and future readers, all the bugs are at the CKEditor end; the Drupal integration is just proxying the editor’s methods.

Wow, thanks for all the work and thank you for confirming it's an issue with CKE5. I implemented the filter for my feature, but it only guesses the intention in the most common scenario - not ideal, but hopefully "good enough." Another idea (just occurred to me) is to use hash-tags in image's alt text which would be extracted and interpreted by the filter (the filter currently uses it for the title of the link which cannot be reliably set otherwise in CKE5) - but I leave that for "maybe later," there are other CKE5 issues I need to fix first.
